# strings and integers accessing and saving

Tags: delphi

Goodday, I have a little problem finishing off a project. I am not very experienced with delphi, but not too bad either.

I am creating a project where people can fill two spaces at once on a website via the Twebbrowser in delphi. For example take a account creating page of any website and lets say there are 4 typing fields(input fields), firstname, lastname, password and repeat password. I just made these up but they should let me understand enough. Every field is in a form. The website is mine and I know everything about it. Firstname and lastname are in form 1 and the passwords are in form 2. Now I want to create some sort of table where I can write these values like so:

| firstname  | 1 | lastname       | 1 |

| password   | 2 | repeatpassword | 2 |

I want to save this to a file of any type and read from it again when I open it. The idea is 4 columns and for starters 2 rows. Might expand it later. But it is important that when the firstname id is found, its form and lastname + its form are accessible and not the ones from password. I hope this explains the project well enough. Databases seem too complicated for this.

Now my question is: What is the best way to save these strings and values to a file so that they can be accessed from the delphi form(and edited)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got only a handful of fields, an inifile is a good and easy solution. You can use the TIniFile class to easily read and write to inifiles.

Comment: +1 Inifiles are great for this, but I always use `TMemIniFile` since I seem to recall plain `TIniFile` had problems on some network drives (it uses the legacy private profile string API calls). All the same, I never trusted `TIniFile` after that but perhaps I'm just paranoid.

Comment: I've never experienced real problems with TIniFile, but you're not the first I heard complaining about it. Besides, TMemIniFile is (a little) faster too, so I think it's better indeed to use TMemIniFile.

Comment: TMemIniFile can be a lot faster depending on the number of entries,  since it buffers all entries and writes them all at once.

Comment: Ok, I have found out how to use the TmemIniFile.saving and loading them. But how do you save them in the format that when you search for one you get the rest of the information too. Like I showed in my exampl in the question. How do you save the string list in this IniFile and how do you load it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Do you want to save the strings with the pipe (`|`) separator, or doesn't it matter? You can use StringList.DelimitedText to get all items in a single string. You can save that string in the inifile. You could even choose not to use the inifile, but instead use `TStringList.SaveToFile` and `LoadFromFile` to save a list of delimited stringlists. But if you have additional questions about this, you may better open a new question, than to have more discussion in the comments here.

Comment: No I mean that with TIniFile I can only get two values together as so:MyInifile.writeinteger('name','string1','string2') and it fills it in as String1=String2 when I load it. But I want the 4 values to be related. So when I save, i save the firstname and 1 and lastname and 1. I'm not sure how I could make the program realize that when I access firstname I should also be able to load the other 3 pieces of information and only them, not the rest of saved things. If you can't answer then I will ask a question. No problem

Comment: take a look at my answer below

Comment: You can use sections for that. Tinifile lets you save values in separate sections which contain related data.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to story things in the registry under the local user, for easy retrieval later and to prevent the casual user from editing it (like they can an edit file)
As with the ini file solution, it's only fun for a limited set of values.

```
Reg := TRegistry.Create;
try
  Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  if Reg.OpenKey('\Software\Lakkerw\myProgram', True) then
    Reg.WriteString('Usr_Name',sUser_name);
    .....
finally
  Reg.CloseKey;
  FreeAndNil(Reg);
end;
```

EDIT: Just saw you requested it to be in a file. I guess this solution wont work for that then :)

Answer (score 0):

Any TStrings object (of which TStringList is a descendant) has the methods SaveToFile and LoadFromFile.

Since you're a beginner (but not too bad :-), I recommend these pages.

http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Files

http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TStringList

EDIT: I see you're having some trouble getting what you want (re four related strings)

OK, relationships are a logical concept. I mean - they can be implemented in many different ways.

First of all, why do you need to save the "repeat password"? that doesn't make sense to me. Usually a UI will ask the user to repeat the password as a form of validation, but that's all it's good for. There's no benefit in storing it for later retrieval is there.

I think you need to save the user's first_name, last_name, and password (3 strings). Have a look at the following piece of code.

```
procedure SaveUserDetails(sFileName: string);
var
  sFirstName, sLastName, sPassword: string;
  slUsers: TStringList;
begin
  sFirstName := txtFirstName.Text;  // these could be from TEdit controls for example
  sLastName := txtLastName.Text;
  sPassword := txtPassword.Text;
  slUsers := TStringList.Create;
  slUsers.Add(sFirstName + ',' + sLastName + ',' + sPassword);
  slUsers.SaveToFile(sFileName);  // that has saved your stringlist to a file
  slUsers.Free;
end;
```

The file will look this

```
Shane,Warne,cricket
```

Now, how to load it...

```
procedure LoadUserDetails(sFileName: string);
var
  sFirstName, sLastName, sPassword: string;
  sTemp: string;
  slUsers: TStringList;
  iPos: integer;  // string position marker we'll use to split the string in 3
begin
  slUsers := TStringList.Create;
  slUsers.LoadFromFile(sFileName); // this loads the file's contents into stringlist
  sTemp := slUsers[0];
  if (Length(sTemp) > 0) then // just to check that there is data there
  begin
    iPos := pos(',', sTemp); // get position of first comma (our "delimiter")
    sFirstName := Copy(sTemp, 0, iPos-1);  // firstName everything upto 1st comma
    sTemp := Copy(sTemp, iPos + 1, Length(sTemp)); // chop off bit we just read
    iPos := pos(',', sTemp); // get position of second comma
    sLastName := Copy(sTemp, 0, iPos-1);  // LastName everything upto 2nd comma
    sTemp := Copy(sTemp, iPos + 1, Length(sTemp)); // chop off bit we just read
    sPassword := sTemp; // that's it
  end;
  slUsers.Free;
end;
```

Now... this far from "good code" but now you know at least 1 way to do your thing. Hope that helps.